# Get WiFi Signal Strength of Connected Network

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-wifi

I'm trying to display the signal strength of the connected WiFi network in my Android app.  I've tried the following:

```
//Receiver for information on the network info
private BroadcastReceiver mNetworkReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        Log.d("INFO", "onReceive()");
        List<ScanResult> scanResult = mWifi.getScanResults();
        for(ScanResult scan : scanResult)
        {
            Log.d("INFO","Network strength: " + String.valueOf(scan.level) + " dBm " + scan.SSID);
        }
    }   
};
```

And then I do the registering/unregistering of my receiver on the onResume()/onPause():

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    mActivity.registerReceiver(mNetworkReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)); //network info
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    mActivity.unregisterReceiver(mNetworkReceiver);
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work.  I also have the `ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` permission enabled.  My receiver is only called if I call `<WiFiManager>.startScan()` manually, but I'm trying to get it to work with my broadcast receiver so that I can always show the signal strength whenever it changes.  I noticed that the `onReceive()` provides a list which is unnecessary if I just want the connected network's stats.  Any way to change that too?

edit: Also, I realize that there are some related questions on this, but the ones I've read weren't too helpful.
edit2: Clarified my question a bit.  The main problem is that my receiver is never called unless I call `startScan()`.

Comment: You're definitely barking up the right tree with WifiManager:, but what about "calculateSignalLevel()" etc: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html

Comment: Wouldn't I need that in my broadcast receiver though?  Right now my receiver isn't even being called unless I manually do a `startScan()`.  Shouldn't my receiver be called every time the signal strength changes?

Comment: @Atlos.. so you want to get inform about wifi signal strength when app start running.. using BReceiver?? clear me if i am wrong, i have done this.we can solve your prob

Comment: @RDC Yes.  So when my app is running it will display the current network strength similar to how the number of bars change at the top of the phone indicating the strength.

Comment: @Atlos.. okay let me modify my code snap according to your need,and let me know if it's helpful for you

Answer (score 5):

well this code is working fine with me to inform WiFi signal strength when it changes using toast, so

**My Receiver** is like this

```
@Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    List<ScanResult> results = wifiDemo.wifi.getScanResults();
    ScanResult bestSignal = null;
    for (ScanResult result : results) {
      if (bestSignal == null
          || WifiManager.compareSignalLevel(bestSignal.level, result.level) < 0)
        bestSignal = result;
    }

    String message = String.format("%s networks found. %s is the strongest.",
        results.size(), bestSignal.SSID);
    Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Log.d("Debug", "onReceive() message: " + message);
  }
```

---

this is what in my **start-up activity** to register Receiver and get Wifi Info on TextView

```
public class WiFiDemo extends Activity {

    WifiManager wifi;
    BroadcastReceiver receiver;

    TextView textStatus;    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Setup UI
        textStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textStatus);      

        // Setup WiFi
        wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        // Get WiFi status
        WifiInfo info = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
        textStatus.append("\n\nWiFi Status: " + info.toString());

        // List available networks
        List<WifiConfiguration> configs = wifi.getConfiguredNetworks();
        for (WifiConfiguration config : configs) {
            textStatus.append("\n\n" + config.toString());
        }

        // Register Broadcast Receiver
        if (receiver == null)
            receiver = new WiFiScanReceiver(this);

        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
                WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
            super.onStop();
    }
    }
```

---

i put scroll view on TextView in **XML layout file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textStatus"
            android:text="WiFi Connections :" />
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

and finally my **manifest** is look like this

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE">
</uses-permission>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE">
</uses-permission>

    <activity android:name=".WiFiDemo" android:label="@string/app_name">
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".WiFiScanReceiver">
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.rdc" />
          </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

still have any trouble let me know!!

Answer (score 2):

Do this in your reciver--

```
final List<ScanResult> results = _wifiManager.getScanResults();
//do it to get connected info..
    //  final WifiInfo wifiInfo = _wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
      //           int connectedRssi= wifiInfo.getRssi();
        if (results != null) {
                for (final ScanResult result : results) {
                int rssi=result.level;
            }
              scanResult(rssi);
        }
```

Make an interface for scan Result and call it in your activity whereever you want to display it...

```
     public void scanResult(int rssi){
        _rssiText.setText(rssi);

      }
```

Manifest permissions--

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" /> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Hope so this will help you...

Comment: This is almost exactly what I already have...  The problem is that my receiver is never called unless I manually call `startScan()`.

Comment: you have to call startScan()...otherwise it will never call the scan reciever....or..apply a check for first time....if(_broadcastReciver==null){ call your reciver here}

Answer (score 2):

If you want just to monitor the current WiFi signal strength you may use `IntentFilter` with `WifiManager.RSSI_CHANGED_ACTION`, not the `WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION`