# Android Getting WiFi signal strength as it changes

Tags: android, android-wifi, rssi

I want to get the Signal strength of the WiFi network I am connected to , as it changes .
This is my broadcast receiver

```
     registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            int info = Wifi.getConnectionInfo().getRssi();
            textStatus.append("\n\n : " + Integer.toString(info));
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.RSSI_CHANGED_ACTION));
```

I am getting it only once . How do i get it as it changes ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389492/get-wifi-signal-strength-of-connected-network

Comment: I already saw that , it does not give the strength as it changes

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: From tests in Android 4.4 and 5.0 the interval between sequential WiFi scans seems to be less than a second. You can take a look at my demo for RF measurements using Android device, here:

https://github.com/panosvas/Measurements

where you can find an implementation of WiFi measurements one after another. I have also created a Server for storing these measurements as well as a remote trigger app using UDP packets where you can find here:

https://github.com/panosvas/IndoorPositioningServer

Actually, you cannot take the RSSI each time it changes because it is possible that the RSSI value changes in a period of mseconds or even faster and each wifi measurement in Android takes approximately 5 seconds depending also on the device.

So, what you advice my answers in the following posts for that:

[Wifi Scanner which scans 20 times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059997/wifi-scanner-which-scans-20-times/27169311#27169311)

[How to update wifi RSSI values without a click button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22201610/how-to-update-wifi-rssi-values-without-a-click-button)